# Unrecognized element 'basicHttpBinding'

Tags: wcf

I hope you can help me, I'm getting:

`Unrecognized element basicHttpBinding`.

In the past, I solved the same problem changing `appPool`, but I can't put it to work now. 
Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: you have an error in your web.config file, but we cant help unless you give some more information

Comment: Sorry guys, I figured out. I have puted <basicHttpBinding> inside <customBinding> ¬¬. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if someone get this error, check if you put `<basicHttpBinding>` inside `<customBinding>`, if yes, move it to `<bindings>`.